# tooltip for a scatter plot matrix - using d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a scatter plot matrix for which I need a tooltip. I tried using the following code, but then, it gives me tooltips at random points and not at the exact cells.

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong ? Or is not possible to generate a tooltip for my data?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}

.axis,
.frame {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line {
  stroke: #ddd;
}

.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.frame {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #aaa;
}

circle {
  fill-opacity: .7;
}

circle.hidden {
  fill: #ccc !important;
}

.extent {
  fill: #000;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="chart3"> </div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 419,
                    size = 130,
                    padding = 19.5,
                    height = 313;

            var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100])
                    .range([padding / 2, size - padding / 2]);

            var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1])
                    .range([size - padding / 2, padding / 2]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom")
                    .ticks(5);

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left")
                    .ticks(5);

            var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(['no chemo', 'induction', 'induction+chemoRT', 'concurrent'])
                    .range(['#ffae19', '#4ca64c', '#4682B4', '#c51b8a']);

            var tip = d3.tip()
                    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
                    .offset([50,70])
                    .html(function (d) {
                        var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
                        xValue = x.invert(coordinates[0]);
                        yValue = y.invert(coordinates[1]);

                        return "<strong> Age Of Patient " + d3.format(".2f")(xValue * 100)+
                                " <br/> Probability of Survival : " + d3.format(".2f")(yValue*100) + " % </strong>";
                    });

            d3.csv("SurvivalProbability.csv", function (error, data) {
                if (error)
                    throw error;

                var domainByTrait = {},
                        traits = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (d) {
                    return (d == 'AgeAtTx' || d == 'Probability of Survival')
                }),
                        n = traits.length;


                traits.forEach(function (trait) {
                    domainByTrait[trait] = d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                        return d[trait];
                    });
                });

                xAxis.tickSize(size * n);
                yAxis.tickSize(-size * n);

                var brush = d3.svg.brush()
                        .x(x)
                        .y(y)
                        .on("brushstart", brushstart)
                        .on("brush", brushmove)
                        .on("brushend", brushend);

                var svg = d3.select("#chart3").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + "," + padding / 2 + ")");

                svg.call(tip);

                svg.selectAll(".x.axis")
                        .data(traits)
                        .enter().append("g")
                        .attr("class", "x axis")
                        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
                            return "translate(" + (n - i - 1) * size + ",0)";
                        })
                        .each(function (d) {
                            x.domain(domainByTrait[d]);
                            d3.select(this).call(xAxis);
                        });

                svg.selectAll(".y.axis")
                        .data(traits)
                        .enter().append("g")
                        .attr("class", "y axis")
                        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
                            return "translate(0," + i * size + ")";
                        })
                        .each(function (d) {
                            y.domain(domainByTrait[d]);
                            d3.select(this).call(yAxis);
                        });

                var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell")
                        .data(cross(traits, traits))
                        .enter().append("g")
                        .attr("class", "cell")
                        .attr("transform", function (d) {
                            return "translate(" + (n - d.i - 1) * size + "," + d.j * size + ")";
                        })
                        .each(plot)
                        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

                // Titles for the diagonal.
                cell.filter(function (d) {
                    return d.i === d.j;
                }).append("text")
                        .attr("x", padding)
                        .attr("y", padding)
                        .attr("dy", ".71em")
                        .text(function (d) {
                            return d.x;
                        });

                cell.call(brush);

                function plot(p) {
                    var cell = d3.select(this);

                    x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
                    y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);

                    cell.append("rect")
                            .attr("class", "frame")
                            .attr("x", padding / 2)
                            .attr("y", padding / 2)
                            .attr("width", size - padding)
                            .attr("height", size - padding);

                    cell.selectAll("circle")
                            .data(data)
                            .enter().append("circle")
                            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                                return x(d[p.x]);
                            })
                            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                                return y(d[p.y]);
                            })
                            .attr("r", 5)
                            .style("fill", function (d) {
                                return color(d.Chemotherapy);
                            });
                }

                var brushCell;

                // Clear the previously-active brush, if any.
                function brushstart(p) {
                    if (brushCell !== this) {
                        d3.select(brushCell).call(brush.clear());
                        x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
                        y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);
                        brushCell = this;
                    }
                }

                // Highlight the selected circles.
                function brushmove(p) {
                    var e = brush.extent();
                    svg.selectAll("circle").classed("hidden", function (d) {
                        return e[0][0] > d[p.x] || d[p.x] > e[1][0]
                                || e[0][1] > d[p.y] || d[p.y] > e[1][1];
                    });
                }

                // If the brush is empty, select all circles.
                function brushend() {
                    if (brush.empty())
                        svg.selectAll(".hidden").classed("hidden", false);
                }

                function cross(a, b) {
                    var c = [], n = a.length, m = b.length, i, j;
                    for (i = - 1; ++i < n; )
                        for (j = - 1; ++j < m; )
                            c.push({x: a[i], i: i, y: b[j], j: j});
                    return c;
                }

                d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", size * n + padding + 20 + "px");

                var legendRectSize = 10;
                var legendSpacing = 10;
                var legend = svg.append("g")
                        .selectAll("g")
                        .data(color.domain())
                        .enter()
                        .append('g')
                        .attr('class', 'legend')
                        .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
                            var height = legendRectSize;
                            var x = 2 * size;
                            var y = (i * height) + 120;
                            return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')';
                        });
                legend.append('rect')
                        .attr('width', legendRectSize)
                        .attr('height', legendRectSize)
                        .style('fill', color)
                        .style('stroke', color);
                legend.append('text')
                        .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
                        .attr('y', legendSpacing)
                        .text(function (d) {
                            return d;
                        });
            });

</script>
```

A screenshot of my data - Survival Probability.csv

```
Ethnicity,AgeAtTx,Site,Tcategory,Nodal_Disease,ecog,Chemotherapy,Local_Therapy,Probability of Survival,KM OS,OS (months),sex
white,65.93972603,supraglottic,T3,N+,0,no chemo,LP/RT alone,0.366190068,0,112.9,Female
white,69.42465753,supraglottic,T3,N+,0,induction,PLRT,0.396018836,0,24.1,Male
white,68.14246575,supraglottic,T3,N0,3,no chemo,LP/RT alone,0.439289384,0,3.566666667,Female
white,40.30410959,supraglottic,T3,N+,1,no chemo,LP/RT alone,0.512773973,1,226.3,Male
white,47.96438356,supraglottic,T3,N+,0,no chemo,PLRT,0.472208904,0,9.6,Female
white,70.3369863,supraglottic,T3,N+,0,no chemo,LP/RT alone,0.324965753,0,25.26666667,Male
white,60.50136986,supraglottic,T3,N+,2,no chemo,LP/RT alone,0.323424658,0,9.5,Female
white,60.72328767,supraglottic,T3,N+,1,no chemo,LP/RT alone,0.321344178,0,15.03333333,Male
white,59.36986301,supraglottic,T3,N0,1,induction,LP/chemoRT,0.646532534,0,4.5,Male
other,57.64931507,supraglottic,T3,N+,1,concurrent,LP/chemoRT,0.662662671,1,52.73333333,Male
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting situation.  It boils down essentially to element append order and mouse-events.  First, let's fix the obvious.  You want a tooltip on each circle, so you shouldn't be calling `tip.show` when you mouse over a cell, but on the circles:

```
cell.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d[p.x]);
   })
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
     return y(d[p.y]);
   })
   .attr("r", 5)
   .style("fill", function(d) {
     return color(d.Chemotherapy);
   })
   .on('mouseover', tip.show)
   .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

But you'll notice with this change, we don't receive the events on our circles.  This is because `svg.brush` is placing a rect over each cell so that you can select with the `extent`, and it's receiving the mouse events.  So to fix that we change the order of drawing to `brush` then `circle`:

```
 var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell")
    .data(cross(traits, traits))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "cell")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (n - d.i - 1) * size + "," + d.j * size + ")";
    });

  // add the brush stuff
  cell.call(brush);
  // now the circles
  cell.each(plot);
```

But we still have a problem.  We've got one more `rect` on top of our circles, the *frame* rect.  Since we don't care about mouse events on it just do a simple:

```
.style("pointer-events", "none");
```

---

Putting this all together:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .axis,
  .frame {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  .axis line {
    stroke: #ddd;
  }
  
  .axis path {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .frame {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #aaa;
  }
  
  circle {
    fill-opacity: .7;
  }
  
  circle.hidden {
    fill: #ccc !important;
  }
  
  .extent {
    fill: #000;
    fill-opacity: .125;
    stroke: #fff;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="chart3"> </div>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
  <script>
    var width = 419,
      size = 130,
      padding = 19.5,
      height = 313;

    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100])
      .range([padding / 2, size - padding / 2]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1])
      .range([size - padding / 2, padding / 2]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5);

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(['no chemo', 'induction', 'induction+chemoRT', 'concurrent'])
      .range(['#ffae19', '#4ca64c', '#4682B4', '#c51b8a']);

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([50, 70])
      .html(function(d) {
        console.log(d)
        var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
        xValue = x.invert(coordinates[0]);
        yValue = y.invert(coordinates[1]);

        return "<strong> Age Of Patient " + d3.format(".2f")(xValue * 100) +
          " <br/> Probability of Survival : " + d3.format(".2f")(yValue * 100) + " % </strong>";
      });

    //d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    //  if (error)
    //     throw error;
    
      var data = [{"Ethnicity":"white","AgeAtTx":"65.93972603","Site":"supraglottic","Tcategory":"T3","Nodal_Disease":"N+","ecog":"0","Chemotherapy":"no chemo","Local_Therapy":"LP/RT alone","Probability of Survival":"0.366190068","KM OS":"0","OS (months)":"112.9","sex":"Female"},{"Ethnicity":"white","AgeAtTx":"69.42465753","Site":"supraglottic","Tcategory":"T3","Nodal_Disease":"N+","ecog":"0","Chemotherapy":"induction","Local_Therapy":"PLRT","Probability of Survival":"0.396018836","KM OS":"0","OS (months)":"24.1","sex":"Male"},{"Ethnicity":"white","AgeAtTx":"68.14246575","Site":"supraglottic","Tcategory":"T3","Nodal_Disease":"N0","ecog":"3","Chemotherapy":"no chemo","Local_Therapy":"LP/RT alone","Probability of Survival":"0.439289384","KM OS":"0","OS (months)":"3.566666667","sex":"Female"},{"Ethnicity":"white","AgeAtTx":"40.30410959","Site":"supraglottic","Tcategory":"T3","Nodal_Disease":"N+","ecog":"1","Chemotherapy":"no chemo","Local_Therapy":"LP/RT alone","Probability of Survival":"0.512773973","KM OS":"1","OS (months)":"226.3","sex":"Male"},{"Ethnicity":"white","AgeAtTx":"47.96438356","Site":"supraglottic","Tcategory":"T3","Nodal_Disease":"N+","ecog":"0","Chemotherapy":"no chemo","Local_Therapy":"PLRT","Probability of Survival":"0.472208904","KM OS":"0","OS (months)":"9.6","sex":"Female"},{"Ethnicity":"white","AgeAtTx":"70.3369863","Site":"supraglottic","Tcategory":"T3","Nodal_Disease":"N+","ecog":"0","Chemotherapy":"no chemo","Local_Therapy":"LP/RT alone","Probability of Survival":"0.324965753","KM OS":"0","OS (months)":"25.26666667","sex":"Male"},{"Ethnicity":"white","AgeAtTx":"60.50136986","Site":"supraglottic","Tcategory":"T3","Nodal_Disease":"N+","ecog":"2","Chemotherapy":"no chemo","Local_Therapy":"LP/RT alone","Probability of Survival":"0.323424658","KM OS":"0","OS (months)":"9.5","sex":"Female"},{"Ethnicity":"white","AgeAtTx":"60.72328767","Site":"supraglottic","Tcategory":"T3","Nodal_Disease":"N+","ecog":"1","Chemotherapy":"no chemo","Local_Therapy":"LP/RT alone","Probability of Survival":"0.321344178","KM OS":"0","OS (months)":"15.03333333","sex":"Male"},{"Ethnicity":"white","AgeAtTx":"59.36986301","Site":"supraglottic","Tcategory":"T3","Nodal_Disease":"N0","ecog":"1","Chemotherapy":"induction","Local_Therapy":"LP/chemoRT","Probability of Survival":"0.646532534","KM OS":"0","OS (months)":"4.5","sex":"Male"},{"Ethnicity":"other","AgeAtTx":"57.64931507","Site":"supraglottic","Tcategory":"T3","Nodal_Disease":"N+","ecog":"1","Chemotherapy":"concurrent","Local_Therapy":"LP/chemoRT","Probability of Survival":"0.662662671","KM OS":"1","OS (months)":"52.73333333","sex":"Male"}];

      var domainByTrait = {},
        traits = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) {
          return (d == 'AgeAtTx' || d == 'Probability of Survival')
        }),
        n = traits.length;


      traits.forEach(function(trait) {
        domainByTrait[trait] = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
          return d[trait];
        });
      });

      xAxis.tickSize(size * n);
      yAxis.tickSize(-size * n);

      var brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .x(x)
        .y(y)
        .on("brushstart", brushstart)
        .on("brush", brushmove)
        .on("brushend", brushend);

      var svg = d3.select("#chart3").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + "," + padding / 2 + ")");

      svg.call(tip);

      svg.selectAll(".x.axis")
        .data(traits)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          return "translate(" + (n - i - 1) * size + ",0)";
        })
        .each(function(d) {
          x.domain(domainByTrait[d]);
          d3.select(this).call(xAxis);
        });

      svg.selectAll(".y.axis")
        .data(traits)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          return "translate(0," + i * size + ")";
        })
        .each(function(d) {
          y.domain(domainByTrait[d]);
          d3.select(this).call(yAxis);
        });

      var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell")
        .data(cross(traits, traits))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "cell")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + (n - d.i - 1) * size + "," + d.j * size + ")";
        });
        
      cell.call(brush);
      
      cell.each(plot);

      // Titles for the diagonal.
      cell.filter(function(d) {
          return d.i === d.j;
        }).append("text")
        .attr("x", padding)
        .attr("y", padding)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.x;
        });

      function plot(p) {
        var cell = d3.select(this);

        x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
        y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);

        cell.append("rect")
          .attr("class", "frame")
          .attr("x", padding / 2)
          .attr("y", padding / 2)
          .attr("width", size - padding)
          .attr("height", size - padding)
          .style("pointer-events", "none");

        cell.selectAll("circle")
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return x(d[p.x]);
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return y(d[p.y]);
          })
          .attr("r", 5)
          .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.Chemotherapy);
          })
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
      }
      
      var brushCell;

      // Clear the previously-active brush, if any.
      function brushstart(p) {
        if (brushCell !== this) {
          d3.select(brushCell).call(brush.clear());
          x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
          y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);
          brushCell = this;
        }
      }

      // Highlight the selected circles.
      function brushmove(p) {
        var e = brush.extent();
        svg.selectAll("circle").classed("hidden", function(d) {
          return e[0][0] > d[p.x] || d[p.x] > e[1][0] || e[0][1] > d[p.y] || d[p.y] > e[1][1];
        });
      }

      // If the brush is empty, select all circles.
      function brushend() {
        if (brush.empty())
          svg.selectAll(".hidden").classed("hidden", false);
      }

      function cross(a, b) {
        var c = [],
          n = a.length,
          m = b.length,
          i, j;
        for (i = -1; ++i < n;)
          for (j = -1; ++j < m;)
            c.push({
              x: a[i],
              i: i,
              y: b[j],
              j: j
            });
        return c;
      }

      var legendRectSize = 10;
      var legendSpacing = 10;
      var legend = svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(color.domain())
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'legend')
        .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
          var height = legendRectSize;
          var x = 2 * size;
          var y = (i * height) + 120;
          return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')';
        });
      legend.append('rect')
        .attr('width', legendRectSize)
        .attr('height', legendRectSize)
        .style('fill', color)
        .style('stroke', color);
      legend.append('text')
        .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
        .attr('y', legendSpacing)
        .text(function(d) {
          return d;
        });
    //});
  </script>
```